# jQuery's :first and :last on the first children of an element

Tags: jquery

I have some simple tables (multiple, all with class="parent") with multiple `<tr>` rows. The `<td>` cells within these rows have tables of their own. I'm trying to target the `<tr>` rows of the *first* (parent) tables, like so:

HTML:

```
<table class="parent"> 
  <tr> <-- match with :first 
    <td> 
      <table> 
        <tr><td></td></tr> 
        <tr><td></td></tr> 
      </table> 
    </td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> <-- match with :last 
    <td> 
      <table> <-- so ignore this child ..
        <tr><td></td></tr> 
        <tr><td></td></tr> <-- .. and do NOT match this <tr> with :last 
      </table> 
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('table.parent').each(function() { 
  $(this).find('tr:first').dostuff(); 
  $(this).find('tr:last').dostuff(); 
});
```

The `:first <tr>` works fine, since that's always the `<tr>` of the parent. But when I try to select the `:last <tr>`, it'll match the last `<tr>` of the nested table, and not the last `<tr>` of the parent table. How can I tell jQuery to only look at the `<tr>`s that are in the parent table, and don't search any further in possible children tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `.find()` (which finds all *descendents*) try `.children()` which finds only direct children:

```
$(this).children('tr:first').dostuff();
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest modifying your selector slightly to ensure that it works on browsers that append a `<tbody>` to tables (like Firefox and Chrome):

```
//tested
$('table.parent > tbody').each(function() {
   $(this).children('tr:first').text('hello').css('background-color', 'red');
   $(this).children('tr:last').text('hello').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```