# JQuery, select first row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've used JQuery to add a "image" button to a few rows in a table. I used the following code:

```
$("#tblResults tr:nth-child(1) td.ResultsHeader span.gridRCHders").each(function(){
    var cat = $.trim($(this).text());
    if(cat.length > 0){
        if(cat.toLowerCase() != "total"){
            options.xAxis.categories.push(cat);
        }
    }
});
```

which basically goes through the first row of the table and stores the values of the cell in a categories array. I'm making changes to an existing site so can't really change the table layout.

What I have noticed is on some pages, more than one table is displayed, my image buttons are added in correctly, but what I need to change is the above code to read the first row of the table that the image is on... I've tried the below but it doens't seem to be working:

```
$("img.ChartButton").click(function(){
    var currentTable = $(this).closest("tr").closest("table").filter("tr:nth-child(1) td.ResultsHeader span.gridRCHders");

    options.xAxis.categories = [];
    currentTable.each(function(){
        var cat = $.trim($(this).text());
        if(cat.length > 0){
            if(cat.toLowerCase() != "total"){
                options.xAxis.categories.push(cat);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatful. Thanks

H

EDIT:
Please find below a copy of one of the tables, as you can see on row 2, I have a "ChartButton" image, This can be on any row from 2 onwards, and they can be more than one in the table. What I need to do is when the image is clicked that the data in row ONE of the current table (they could be more than one table on the page) is read in and saved in to the categories array (see above code). Hope this helps.

```
 <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0" class="whiteBorder">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">Jan</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">Feb</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">Mar</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">Apr</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">May</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">Jun</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">Jul</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">Aug</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">Sep</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">Oct</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">Nov</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">Dec</span></td>
            <td width="40" valign="bottom" align="left" class="ResultsHeader" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="gridRCHders">Total</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="lGreyBG">
            <td align="left" colspan="15">
                <span class="gridTXT"><b>KPI</b>&nbsp;<img width="20" alt="Chart" src="Images/chart_bar.png" id="c0_1" class="ChartButton"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="lGreyBGalt">
            <td nowrap="" class="ResultsHeader"><span class="gridRCHders">Pre Conversion %</span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>65 %</i></span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>65 %</i></span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>66 %</i></span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>62 %</i></span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>67 %</i></span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>67 %</i></span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>68 %</i></span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>69 %</i></span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>0 %</i></span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>0 %</i></span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>0 %</i></span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>0 %</i></span></td>
            <td nowrap="" align="right"><span class="gridTXT"><i>66 %</i></span></td>
        </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**
Finally have it working, below is the line I had to use for it to get to the right data in the first row...

```
var $row = $(this).closest('table').children('tbody').children('tr:first').children('td.ResultsHeader').children('span.gridRCHders');
```

I'm not sure why I needed all the children calls, as I did try the following first which **didn't** work:

```
var $row = $(this).closest('table').children('tbody').children('tr:first td.ResultsHeader span.gridRCHders');
```

Thanks to everyone below for the help.

Comment: Maybe you could give us some HTML to work with, specifying what the img is you're working from in the click and what is the tag you want to select, this allows us to better set up a jQuery selector for you

Comment: @Alexander Varwijk - Edited the post and added in the HTML table, as mentioned  I need to read in the first row, what In this case, I need to store the month values into the categories array.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ok so if an image in a table is clicked you want the data of the first row of the table this image is in.

```
//image click stuff here {
$(this). // our image
closest('table'). // Go upwards through our parents untill we hit the table
children('tr:first'); // Select the first row we find

var $row = $(this).closest('table').children('tr:first');
```

`parent()` will only get the direct parent, `closest` should do what we want here.
From jQuery docs: *Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.*

Comment: I tried putting in just upto the parents part for the table, but this returned the parent table, plus the parent table of the table, so I changed it to be just .parent('table') to get the first parent, but this just returns ()... strange.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, I've tried closest, which does indeed return the table, but as soon as I put children part on, it seems to not return anything.

Comment: @harag I somehow didn't get notified of your comment. .children finds only direct decendants and since you have a tbody in there (missed that sorry) the TR is not found as direct decendant. You could use find() instead which will work in this case (It won't work as well for e.g. :last http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318445/jquerys-first-and-last-on-the-first-children-of-an-element) .children('tbody > tr:first') could work too.

Comment: I want to get the first row and then all the column of that row except the last one... How can I achieve that?

Comment: concise and documented

Comment: Go give Roger Gusmao credit, but perhaps try `find` instead of `children`.

Answer (score 18):

late in the game , but this worked for me:

```
$("#container>table>tbody>tr:first").trigger('click');
```

Comment: doesn't matter - it illustrates another example of how to get to the element in question.

Answer (score 10):

[This is a better solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/kQRj8/), using:

`$("table tr:first-child").has('img')`

Answer (score 4):

Can't you use the [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector ?

something like: `tr:first`

Comment: I've tried changing the filter in my code to tr:first as you suggest, but it doens't seems to be retuning any elements.

Comment: @harag: did you see anything when debuging (e.g. with Firebug) >> you can try some code to see what it returns and then find the right selector. Thus, you'll be able to see what's the best code

Comment: I've put a break point on the row that starts with "var currentTable = $(this).closest("tr")" but after the row is ran the "currentTable" variable just says "Jquery ()".

Comment: I've tried "var currentTable = $(this).closest("table").children("tr");" and this returns nothing, but if I leave off the children part, it returns the table element.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is not necessary, you can use only javascript.

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
   ......
  <tr>...</tr>
</table>
```

The table object has a collection of all rows.

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('table');
var rows =  myTable.rows;
var firstRow = rows[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you try to use function "children" it will not be succesfull because it's possible to the table has a first child like 'th'. So you have to use function 'find' instead.

Wrong way:

```
var $row = $(this).closest('table').children('tr:first');
```

Correct way:

```
 var $row = $(this).closest('table').find('tr:first');
```

Comment: You could also have table > thead > tr and then table > tbody > tr. So you might need to specify whether you want the first row from the thead or the tbody. `find('tr:first')` will select the tr in the thead.